# Long Compile Time for Big Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-construction, autolayout, compiler-optimization

I have big project which autolayout enabled and used for all pages and has 1 storyboard, 60 view controller, more than 90 different view. 
Compile time takes 90 100 second to finish when something change from storyboard.

How can I shorten project's compile time? 
I guess autolayout could be the reason of long compile process, where should I look to get a clue for it.

Sorry I don't know which information should I give about project thus please ask if you need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are Divide your storyBoard in Sub-storyboard.

```
Main.StoryBoard
```

Divide To:

```
Main1.storyBoard , Main2.storyBoard , Main3.storyBoard
```

and each of the `storyBoard` take 10. `ViewController`.

Comment: hey kirit It's long work to do that, but are you sure one storyboard is the problem of all that compile time? Is there any other way to prevent it?

Comment: Not long work, Copy these ViewController and Paste on New StoryBoard. it is easy and compile fine